# SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT "Added / Excluded" column

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to find a way to get all ("None" from the "Added / Excluded" column) search terms using the AdWords API.

If anyone had the same problem and has found a solution please share.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Added/Excluded column is available only on the interface but not through API.We can only compare the search queries with keyword report and find out added/excluded.

Answer (score 1):

It's available (now) by pushing the API version:

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
    ' SELECT Query, Impressions, QueryTargetingStatus ' +
    ' FROM SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
    ' WHERE CampaignName = "' + campaignName + '" ' +
    ' DURING LAST_30_DAYS ', {
        apiVersion: 'v201708'
    });
```